# In Weka make a arff file from text file

Tags: machine-learning, weka

In naive byes classifier i want to find out the accuracy from my train and test. But my train set is like

Happy: `absolution abundance abundant accolade accompaniment accomplish accomplished achieve achievement acrobat admirable admiration adorable adoration adore advance advent advocacy aesthetics affection affluence alive allure aloha`

Sad: `abandon abandoned abandonment abduction abortion abortive abscess absence absent absentee abuse abysmal abyss accident accursed ache aching adder adrift adultery adverse adversity afflict affliction affront aftermath aggravating`

Angry: `abandoned abandonment abhor abhorrent abolish abomination abuse accursed accusation accused accuser accusing actionable adder adversary adverse adversity advocacy affront aftermath aggravated aggravating aggravation aggression aggressive aggressor agitated agitation agony alcoholism alienate alienation`

For test set
data: `Dec 7, 2014 ... This well-known nursery rhyme helps children practice emotions, like happy, sad, scared, tired and angry. If You're Happy and You Know It is ...`

Now the problem is how do i convert them into arff file

Answer (score 0):

Your training set is not appropriate for training a model for Weka however these information can be used in feature extraction.

Your Test set can be converted into an arff file. From every message extract these basics features like 
1. Any form of the word 'Happy' is present or not
2. Any form of the word 'Sad' is present or not
3. Any form of the word 'Angry' is present or not
4. TF-IDF
etc.

then for some messages (say 70%) you should assign one class {Happy, Sad, Angry} manually and for remaining 30% you can test through your model.

More about arff file is given here:
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Answer (score 0):

As written before your "training data" is not real training data. Training data should be texts similar to the data you are using for Testing. However, in your example it is merely a list of words. My gut feeling is that you would be better of to avoid using weka, count the number of occurrence in each category, and the take the one with most matches.

In case you want use Weka I'd recommend to use the toolbox https://www.knime.org which nicely integrates with weka.
You should then convert your data into a bag of words representation. This is basically you have the number of times each word occurs in each of the texts as features.
Also for this Knime has nice package. http://www.tech.knime.org/files/KNIME-TextProcessing-HowTo.pdf